# ItemsControl does not stretch vertically

Tags: wpf, prism, itemscontrol, stretch

I have a PRISM v5 application which cause me some trouble.

I have three `ItemsControls` in my `UserControl`'s `Grid`:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="50"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Header region-->
    <ItemsControl
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.HeaderRegion}"/>

    <!--Main region-->
    <ItemsControl
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.MainRegion}">
    </ItemsControl>

    <!--Menu region-->
    <ItemsControl
        Background="DarkGoldenrod"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.MenuRegion}">
    </ItemsControl>
```

When I run them and insert views with unspecified height, they will not fill out all the space available.
But they fill out the horizontal space (width), as seen below:

[image: Prism project not stretching[1]]

I have seen SO many suggestions of this:

```
    <ItemsControl
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.MainRegion}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid></Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

But it does not work, because I get this error message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='SecondView'
System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='SecondView'
```

I have even searched Google to page 4 before making new searches - I am truly desperate for something that can stretch this out vertically.

**Update 1:**

So I changed one of the `ItemsControl` to a `ContentControl`:

```
<!--Header region-->
<ItemsControl
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.HeaderRegion}"/>

<!--Main region-->
<ContentControl
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.MainRegion}"/>
```

I load my `SecondView` into the `ContentControl`, which is a `UserControl` with the following content:

```
<Grid
    Background="IndianRed"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    MinHeight="200"
    MinWidth="200"/>
```

I do so this way:

```
var obj = _container.Resolve<SecondView>();
var region = _manager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];
region.Add(obj);
```

It now looks like this:

[image: Edit 1[2]]

Still not stretching to the bottom of the page.

**Update 2:**
And it turn out `ContentControl` is the answer for this.
But you cannot have an unspecified height. I had the following:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="50"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Changing the `Height` for the second `RowDefinition` gives a wanted result. But now I need to know how high it must be, because it won't scale.

So I looked other places for a solution.
Someone (somewhere, I do not recall where) said this might do the trick:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <resources:VisibilityToStarHeightConverter x:Key="VisibilityToStarHeightConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="50" />
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToStarHeightConverter}, ConverterParameter=5}" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Binding it to a class like this:

```
public class VisibilityToStarHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            return new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);
        }
        else
        {
            if (parameter == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter");
            }

            return new GridLength(double.Parse(parameter.ToString(), culture), GridUnitType.Star);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But I can't load the application without getting a `InvalidCastException` on the `(Visivility)value`

Anyone knows how to dynamically see how tall the windows should be?

Comment: What is the content of the views? Some controls will simply not stretch. The best example is a Stackpanel. In vertical orientation, it will not stretch beyond the minimum vertical space required by its children.

Comment: I use a ``Grid`` with background color set to green and one with red @Gusdor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an ItemsControl stretch to fill all availible space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653047/how-do-i-make-an-itemscontrol-stretch-to-fill-all-availible-space)

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemsControl` is vertically stretched, but your views are being added as items within the `ItemsControl`.

Use `ContentControl` for your regions instead.

Comment: That'll be a hassle to fix (there's more than just this), but I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: It's still not functional with a ContentControl.
Do you have more suggestions?

Comment: Let me take that back. Found the error on my height settings.

Comment: Let me correct that too - If I specify a height, it works (but I do not want that). It still does not work. Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your grid row as stretched, like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="50"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="50" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Same result as in Update 1. Try to see my Update 2