# How do I make an ItemsControl stretch to fill all available space?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl, with its ItemsSource bound to a list of items. The size of each of the items is as small as they can be, what I need is for the control and the items in the control to stretch to fit all available space.

I tried setting VerticalAlignment to Stretch on both the control, and its items (using a style). I also tried wrapping the ItemsControl in a DockPanel, and docking the ItemsControl to the bottom. How do I have the ItemsControl dynamically resize?

Also some, but not all, of the item's visibilities are set to Collapsed (through the same style). Will that be a factor in how this needs to be done?

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Owner.LoadPointCharts}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    x:Name="ItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle><!--Height="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}}"-->
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />

                <Setter Property="Visibility">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CompareIndexToVisibilityConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Index" />
                        <Binding Path="SelectedIndex" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            </Style >
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The items in my ItemsControl are vertically stretched by default. How does your ItemTemplate look like?

Comment: There is no change to the ItemTemplate. The ContentPresenter is binding to an object that has a DataTemplate which is template using a DataTemplate (as per MVVM). The DataTemplate is of a WPF Toolkit Chart control. I set VerticalAlignment to Stretch for **that** too.

Comment: Try how it looks if you replace that DataTemplate by one that only has e.g. a TextBlock. Then set the TextBlock Background.

Comment: @Clemens   I did that. It is as small as it can possibly be without running over the content.

Comment: You could also set the Background of the DockPanel to see if that is actually stretched.

Comment: @Clemens It is (I said as much in the comments in the answer below, which unfortunately didn't work)

Comment: @Clemens No, I have not, what would I set it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ought to work, depending on what contains the outermost `Grid`.

By default, a Grid will stretch to fill its container, and it'll cause its contents to stretch to fill itself. If you're putting the `ItemsControl` in a `DockPanel` and setting `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` on the `ItemsControl`, it'll fill the bottom of the `DockPanel`, so if I understand correctly, that's not what you want.

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Owner.LoadPointCharts}"
        x:Name="ItemsControl"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />

                <Setter Property="Visibility">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CompareIndexToVisibilityConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Index" />
                            <Binding Path="SelectedIndex" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style >
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

`Grid` is kind of the Swiss Army boat anchor of XAML layout. Throw 'em around everywhere.

If you want to dock other stuff in a `DockPanel`, here's a simple `DockPanel` layout:

```
<Window xmnls:blah="blah blah etc.">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <!-- Menu Items-->
            </Menu>
            <Grid>
                <!-- 
                This assumes we've got a DataTemplate in a resource dictionary  
                somewhere with DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}" 
                -->
                <ContentControl
                    Content="{Binding}"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I tried putting the ItemsControl in a grid, it did not work.

Comment: @kleineg What does the whole XAML file look like? There must be something that's not stretching.

Comment: When I set the background of my DockPanel to red, it filled all of the area I wanted it to. And despite being docked to the bottom, the ItemsControl was all at the top

Comment: For that matter, I set the background of the ItemsControl to red, and it also filled the space I wanted it to. But the individual items didn't expand to fill the space.

Comment: @kleineg Ohhhh! Now I understand. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, not one that will add a lot to the discussion. It is a wide open space, with a couple objects stacked on each other. The objects are as small as they can possibly be (collapsed to fit the content without squishing it). But this is a work project so I can't send screenshots of it.

Comment: @kleineg What do you mean "stacked on each other"? Side by side, or superimposed? Are you trying to make your items stretch vertically, say, so if there are two, each takes up half the vertical space? The way to do that is to use a Grid for an ItemsPanel, which gets uglyish. Doable though.

Comment: Then are stacked one on top of the other. I am trying to get them to stretch vertically. At least if there is a list of one item it should take up the whole space.

Comment: @kleineg You need a grid for that. Is there a possibility that sometimes there will be enough items to require a scrollbar? To make that work, you'll need to a) set ItemsControl.ItemsPanel to an ItemsPanelTemplate containing a Grid (easy), and b) write an attached property to detect when items are added to the ItemsControl, and set Grid.Row appropriately on the newly added items, plus adding/subtracting Grid RowDefinitions as needed. That's a hassle; is it worth it?

Comment: This turns into quite a bit of work to stretch something.

Comment: ...Yes. Me: "Of course I can have it ready for the head of engineering to look at by the end of the day"

Comment: I already figured out the optimal size for **my** monitor, if I run out of time I can set the height to a fixed size (I tried, it works) and it looks good. Unless anyone tries running it on a different monitor.

Comment: @kleineg "Demo (n): That which looks right as long as the presenter is the only one who interacts with it." I've done a few of those.

Comment: Thank you for all the help the other day. Let me ask a clarifying question. I should not have enough items to require a scrollbar, should I still write an attached property to set the height?

Comment: @kleineg If you're using a Grid for the ItemsPanel, you'll always have to have an attached property or something to add RowDefinitions/ColumnDefinitions to the Grid, and set Grid.Row and/or Grid.Column on the items.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out, I used a setter to set the height of the item to the ActualHeight of its owner, it was easy to put in a converter to divide by n. Thank you again.

Comment: @kleineg Ohhh! Very slick!

Comment: @kleineg If it won't scroll, UniformGrid might be perfect as an ItemsPanel. Just found out about that one.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer is a little too complex in my opinion.
Also setting the positions of your items in a Grid can be annoying.
UniformGrid is what you need.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found out that `ItemsControl` by default uses a `StackPanel` for his children. Replacing this with a `Grid` solved the problem:

```
 <ItemsControl>
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Edit: This only works for one child element!

Comment: Grid as template doesn't work because items are placed in the same position and overlap each other!

Comment: You are right, I only used it with one child element. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Grid as Template won't work since items are put over under. Using a DockPanel works fine:

```
  <ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Using a DockPanel causes only the last item to stretch and fill the available space, so items won't be uniform.